# d3 transition for transform translate not working for DIV

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

Why is the transform property not working for DIV in D3?
It works for any svg elements, but not for "div". Any alternate solution?

**NOT WORKING**

```
d3.select("div")
  .transition()
  .style("transform","translate(0px,-500px)");
```

**WORKING**

```
d3.select("circle")
  .transition()
  .style("transform","translate(0px,-500px)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the old version d3.v3.6

The issue is fixed now and it works for DIV or any HTML element.

Try the latest version of d3 or any version from d3.v3.7

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases

It works!

Comment: Could share your combined working HTML, CSS, and JS? I'm having trouble translating a div with D3 myself. Here's a quick demo start, thanks! jsbin.com/wogowa

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned,  d3 doesn't support the transitioning of CSS3 transforms for HTML elements out of the box.  You'll have to create a custom string interpolator to do it for you.

Note: You'll have to find out the initial translate of the element your wanting to animate. This also doesn't take into account vendor-prefixes.

```
    var startTranslateState = 'translate(0px,0px)';
    var endTranslateState = 'translate(0px,-500px)';
    var translateInterpolator = d3.interpolateString(startTranslateState, endTranslateState);

    d3.select("div")
        .transition()
        .styleTween('transform', function (d) {
            return translateInterpolator;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `div` is not an `SVG` element.

Positioning with a transform style can be handled only within `SVG`.

To handle position of the `div`, just create something like this:

```
d3.select("div")
 .style("position","absolute")
 .style("top","0px")
 .transition()
 .style("top","50px");
```

For more info about positioning regular XHTML elements, visit http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.

Comment: jiri, you know what? I wanted to use Hardware accelerated CSS properties to make the transitions smooth and silky. Hence I am trying with transform, translate. I very well know that "top, left" is going to work.

I am writing my own transition method for this case. It seems d3 doesn't support this property in style method and only supports in attr.

Answer (score -1):

just

```
d3.select('div')
 .style('transition-duration', '.5s')
 .style('transform', 'translate(0px, -500px)');
```

**not**

```
d3.select('div')
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .style('transform', 'translate(0px, -500px)');
```

use `transition-duration` when you are dealing not-svg element
It doing very well !